# ASPTwitter library fails when using special characters

Tags: api, twitter, asp-classic, vbscript, tweets

I am trying to update an old ASP classic Twitter program that my work currently uses to use the new OAUTH.  I am not an ASP programmer but I managed to find the ASPTwitter library posted online by Tim Acheson at http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2013/jun/asptwitter

Everything works, as we have our own code searching our database and passing on a built string to the ASPTwitter code to tweet.

The catch is that it will fail with the

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

error message if there is so much as a "." period in the string.  Every possible special character besides letters and numbers causes a fail.

We have many posts that will include various symbols as well as URLs.

I have searched all over and have not been able to find a solution.  Comments on Tim's site have mentioned it but no solutions yet.  Everyone here has been very helpful so I was hoping someone might have a solution.

I can't post the code as there are about 6 files and I don't know which one is causing the issue.

Thank you so much for the help!

Edit:

This is a block of the 300+ line file where the issue happens, I hope that the cause can be found here too.

```
' Gets bearer token for application-only authentication from Twitter API 1.1.
' Application-user authentication: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/using-oauth
' and: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request
' API endpoint statuses/update (post a tweet): https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update
Private Function UpdateStatusJSON(sStatus)

    Dim sURL : sURL = API_BASE_URL + "/1.1/statuses/update.json"

    Dim oXmlHttp: Set oXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 

    oXmlHttp.open "POST", sURL, False



    sStatus = "this is from the ASPTwitter dot asp file"


    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "emiratesjobpost.com"
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "OAuth " & GetOAuthHeader(sURL, sStatus)

    oXmlHttp.send "status=" & Server.URLEncode(sStatus) ' Encoded spaces as + in request body.

    UpdateStatusJSON = oXmlHttp.responseText

    Set oXmlHttp = Nothing

    REM: A JSON viewer can be useful here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
    ' To fix error message "Read-only application cannot POST" go to your application's "Application Type" settings at dev.twitter.com/apps and set "Access" to "Read and Write".
    ' After changing access to read/write you must click the button to generate new auth tokens and then use those.
    Response.Write "<textarea cols=""100"" rows=""3"" >" & UpdateStatusJSON & "</textarea>" : Response.Flush()

End Function
```

If I replace the "dot" with "." in the "sStatus" line, it breaks

Comment: does it break if you use `oXmlHttp.send "status=" & sStatus` instead ? ie: removing the urlencode?

Answer (score 0):

Do your pages use UTF-8 encoding?  Open them in Notepad, select save as from the file menu, and if ansi coding is selected then change it to UTF-8.

See this link for more things you can do

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: I was hoping that would fix the issue but I made sure every asp file was UTF-8 and I still get the issue.  If I include a period in the message, it reports it can't authenticate, take out the period and it posts.  I edited the first post to include at least the code around where the bug happens, which I hope helps.